# Set label of CategoryAxis into barChart javafx

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, axis

I have created a barChart in javaFX and I have a problem with categoryAxis. Practice I would like to divide the number of CategoryAxis by 1000. For the moment the graph I get is this:
[image: first img]
When I divide the values by 1000 then the graph changes the y axis. 
[image: second img]

How should I do to get the xaxis values as the second graph with barChart of the first pictures?

Class to populate and show the graph.

```
    package application;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.math.RoundingMode;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import spectrogram.SpectrogramExtractor;
    public class ControllerSpectrogram {

        private final static double MINSPECTROGRAMHZ = 20.0; 
        static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");            

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static void plotSpectrogramFull(File file, Stage stage) {
            df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
            final CategoryAxis xAxisSpectrogram = new CategoryAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxisSpectrogram = new NumberAxis();

             final BarChart<String,Number> scatterChartSpectrogram = 
                        new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxisSpectrogram,yAxisSpectrogram);
            ArrayList<Double> extractedData; 
            ArrayList<Double> extractedTime; 

            scatterChartSpectrogram.getData().clear();
            scatterChartSpectrogram.setOpacity(0.8);
            scatterChartSpectrogram.setAnimated(true);
            xAxisSpectrogram.setLabel("Time(s)");
            yAxisSpectrogram.setLabel("Spectrogram(Hz)");

            try {

                extractedData = SpectrogramExtractor.extractionSpectrum();
                extractedTime = SpectrogramExtractor.pointTime();
                Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
                for (int i = 0; i < extractedData.size(); i=i+2) {
                    if (extractedData.get(i)> MINSPECTROGRAMHZ) {
                        extractedTime.set(i, extractedTime.get(i)/1000);
                        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(df.format(extractedTime.get(i)), extractedData.get(i)));
                    }
                }
                Scene scene = new Scene(scatterChartSpectrogram, 1000, 600);
                scatterChartSpectrogram.getData().add(series);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
                extractedData.clear();
            } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method (in other class)

```
public class SpectrogramExtractor {
    static ArrayList<Double> pointTime = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Double> pointTime(){    
    Double countTime = 0;   
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    countTime = countTime + 0.0196356952; 
    pointTime.add(countTime);
    return pointTime;
    }
public static ArrayList<Double>extractionSpectrum(){
//and you can try to populate extractedData whit 100 elements (what you want)
}
}
```

Comment: That looks strange.... Can you create a [MCVE] just using mock (i.e. hard-coded) data, and [edit] your question to include it? I can't see how changing the x-values could change the y-values like that.

Comment: ok, I try to change. however, the problem arises only if I use a barchart and then a categoryAxis. if I use a line chart and a numberAxis the problem does not arise. Then the error should be in the conversion from ArrayList of string to double, but do not understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: I have edited my code in answer as you requested. can you help me?

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the problem with that code.

Comment: unfortunately, the classes to be included are so many because the extraction of values is complex. You have at least some idea about why I have this problem?

Comment: No idea; as I said it looks weird. That's why I suggested you try to reproduce the problem with hard-coded data, instead of including all the irrelevant computation. I assume you can just check that the values you're getting from those other classes are the values you expect, independently of the chart.